# Bootstrap 3 - .visible-md has undesirable behavior after 'removing' lg breakpoint

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working with a website where I'm trying to "remove" the `lg` breakpoint as it is undesirable since the content is typically rather text-heavy. However, as it may make sense to use the `lg` breakpoint in the future, **I would like to leave the Bootstrap source unmodified.**

Here is what I have already tried:

- Modified Sass variables (in `_variables.scss`)

  ```
  $screen-md-min: 970px; // MD: Tablets (portrait) + Desktop
  $screen-lg-min = $screen-md-min;
  ```

  I got this idea from [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22656490/2831961), but it hasn't worked for me completely. When I go to use `.visible-lg`, the breakpoints work as they should. When I use `.visible-md`, which in my mind should now be logically equivalent, it doesn't display for anything greater than or equal to the `md` breakpoint.

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <p><b>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</b></p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="visible-xs">2 column width mobile: dynamic</div>
        <div class="visible-sm">2 column width tablet: 93px</div>
        <div class="visible-lg">2 column width desktop: 148px</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2"><p class="grid-txt">2</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><p class="grid-txt">2</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><p class="grid-txt">2</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><p class="grid-txt">2</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><p class="grid-txt">2</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><p class="grid-txt">2</p></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="visible-xs">3 column width mobile: dynamic</div>
        <div class="visible-sm">3 column width tablet: 146px</div>
        <div class="visible-md">3 column width desktop: 229px</div>
        <div class="visible-lg">3 column width desktop: blah</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"><p class="grid-txt">3</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><p class="grid-txt">3</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><p class="grid-txt">3</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><p class="grid-txt">3</p></div>
  </div>  
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

If this doesn't make sense, please feel free to comment asking for additional information! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I discovered this morning, it turns out that while the grid only needs the `$screen-*-min` variables in Bootstrap's code, the `$screen-*-max` is used for responsive utilities, like `.visible-*` and `.hidden-*`. Therefore, anyone with the same problem should just create a sentinel value (or something close since SASS doesn't have a maximum hard coded number or function (like a Number.max() or something like that).

In my case, a simple `$screen-md-max: 100000px;` in my SASS did the trick.